# Can we write a Lucene query to verify if an item exists in a list of Elastic Search or not?

Tags: java, lucene

How to write a Lucene query in order to search if an item exists in a list of Elastic Search or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of Elastic Search". You can [edit] your question to clarify the problem. Please also show what you have tried, and what the result was. Also show us what result you want to achieve. Please avoid screenshots - show us the text (formatted).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site often works best when you provide a _specific_ example illustrating a _specific_ problem you are facing. As it currently stands, your question needs some additional details and clarity.